# Free font alternative to Code Pro?

Tags: font-recommendation, sans-serif

While looking for some fonts for a web design project I stumbled across the [Code Pro](http://fontfabric.com/code-pro/) font:

[image: Code Pro]

Can someone recommend a similar font that's free? I really like the symmetry of this font and want to use it for some headers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about resource gathering, not design.

Comment: I don't know about off-topic (why do we have the font-recommendation tag, then?) but it would be helpful if Michael included more info about what he's tried and what he's looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps their free version of the same font? :) http://www.dafont.com/code.font

Comment: it's missing a fair amount of punctuation

Comment: Probably why it's free. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Indeed Code Pro has the **free** version of Bold and Light on DaFont (link above).
2. I’ve used AvantGardGothEF font that is close to Code Pro.
3. Another alternative is the **[TeX Gyre Adventor Font Family](http://gust-e-foundry.1001fonts.com)**, which is free for commercial use.